# How to cache spacy model in gitlab runner when building docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab, spacy

I use docker and gitlab. My docker file is like this

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install
RUN pip3 install wheel
RUN pip3 install spacy
RUN python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

wheel and spacy packages are cached in the GitLab runner when I build the docker container, but not the spacy model.

Is there a way to cache the en_core_web_md model in the GitLab runner too, so that the model can be installed without downloading it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. Instead of installing the model using following command,

```
RUN python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

First, you need to download the model

```
RUN pip3 download https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_md-2.2.0/en_core_web_md-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

And then install it.

```
RUN pip3 install /en_core_web_md-2.1.0.tar.gz
```

When you re-run the pipeline, model won't download again.

Comment: Hi, are these complete instructions? because the 2nd command yields: `No such file or directory: '/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1.tar.gz'` (I'm using the correct version here, it's just updated)

Comment: Nevermind, realized this is specifically for Gitlab.